# Starting jus coded C# service . while(true)-loop didn't work

Tags: c#, service

I have service written C# and Visual Studio 2012 and NetFrameWork 4.5 and this is code for OnStart-event

After installing service I try to start it and it did'n work and 
Error is:

Windows could not start the DPrintServer service on Local Computer

> Error 1053:The service did not respond to start or control request in
>   timely fashion.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {




        string dirx = @"D:\tempsi";
        //Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"D:\tmp");
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirx);
        /*Ini.IniFile ini = new Ini.IniFile("PrintServer.ini");
        string smtp_server = ini.IniReadValue("smtp", "server");
        string from_email = ini.IniReadValue("from", "fromemail");
        string to_email = ini.IniReadValue("from", "toemail");
        string directory = ini.IniReadValue("settings", "dir");
        */
        string smtp_server = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("server");
        string from_email = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("fromemail");
        string to_email = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("toemail");
        string ddirectory = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("dir");
        string attach_dir = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("attachdir");
        string filename = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("filename");
        string subject = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("subject");
        string mailcontent = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("mailcontent");
        //string directory = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("dir");
        /* while(true)
         {*/
        int counter = 1;
        while (true)
        {

            //counter++;
            if (File.Exists(attach_dir + filename))
            {


                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                /*startInfo.FileName = "batti.bat";
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                //startInfo.Arguments = file;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
                startInfo.FileName = "batti2.bat";
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
                */
                startInfo.FileName = "blat.exe";
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.Arguments = "-install " + smtp_server + " " + from_email;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
                startInfo.FileName = "blat.exe";
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.Arguments = mailcontent + " -to " + to_email + " -subject " + subject + " -attach " + attach_dir + filename;
                var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
                process.WaitForExit();

                File.Delete(attach_dir + filename);
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                stopwatch.Stop();


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That while loop will never finish, so the service will never finish loading...

Comment: while (true) will never be false

Comment: Use a FileSystemWatcher to tell you when the file exists? Put that logic in a timer callback?

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop.  So as far as the host system is concerned, your application is never responding.  Thus, it never successfully "starts" (`OnStart` never returns) and the host terminates the apparently broken process.

This implies that you want your service to do something every second:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

You can accomplish this with a `Timer` object.  All you would really need to do in `OnStart` is initialize that object:

```
this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
this.timer.Interval = 1000;
this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimerTick);
this.timer.Start();
```

Then have a handler for the tick event:

```
public void OnTimerTick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    // perform your once-every-second logic here
}
```

This makes more appropriate use of the system without manually sleeping a thread and using an infinite loop, which as you're seeing causes an application to appear to hang indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks David ! :) Now it works correctly . I owe your one.